# Using Flutter FFMPEG_KIT to convert a sequence of RGBA images into a mp4 video

Tags: flutter, image, video, ffmpeg, rgba

I’m trying to convert a sequence of RGBA byte images into an MP4 video by using Flutter `FFMPEGKit` package. The following is the code snippet but it gives me an error. I’m not sure what is the correct option that I should use to convert a set of `rawrgba` images to a video. I appreciate any help.

```
 static Future<void> videoEncoder() async {
    appTempDir = '${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/workPath';
   
    FFmpegKit.execute(
           '-hide_banner -y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba -i appTempDir/input%d.rgba -c:v mpeg4  -r 12 appTempDir/output.mp4')
     .then((session) async {
       final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();
      if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
        print('SUCCESS');
      } else if (ReturnCode.isCancel(returnCode)) {
        print('CANCEL');
      } else {
        print('ERROR');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The image `rgba` data is saved via the following code snippet.

```
Utils.getBuffer(renderKey).then((value) async {
        ui.Image buffer = value;
        final data =
            await buffer!.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba);
        Uint8List uData = data!.buffer.asUint8List();
        VideoUtil.saveImageFileToDirectory(uData, 'input$frameNum.rgba');
        frameNum++;
        });
```